# Finding the source of a 301 redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I have a WordPress website at https://newable.xyz which is fine, if I go to https://newable.xyz/wp-admin I get redirected to https://newable.co.uk/money/financewp-admin.

This is definitely a 301 redirect.

I've tried the following things:

- Deleting the redirecting plugin and all of its data
- Clearing my browser cache
- Using multiple different browsers
- Using InPrivate/ Incognito
- Using a fresh .htaccess file

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Have you restarted your Apache2 service since the `.htaccess` got updated?

Comment: have you resolved this issue ? Seems to have been fixed

Answer (score 0):

try search in your active WP theme - `wp_redirect` or `wp_safe_redirect`

Answer (score 0):

_search in the theme to see if there is a wp_redirect or wp_safe_redirect as Vasyl said
_deactivate all plugins, both default and mu (a.k.a. mu-plugins) and analyse which one is causing you problems (if there is one that creates conflicts or creates the redirect).
_Try looking in the htaccess file (mod rewrite) of the root, **every folder can have its own htaccess**. You can have more than one .htaccess file on your hosting account, but each directory or folder can only have one, pay attention.
_Try to see if there is a server configuration (many hosting services have the ability to put a redirect to another domain)
-Delete the wordpress package in case it has been polluted with some injected code and download and reupload it.